# C# encryption and C++ decryption Rijndael

Tags: c#, c++, encryption

I am working C# encryption and C++ decryption for an application. Here is the code for C#

```
private static byte[] iv = { 0xb1, 0x59, 0x12, 0xe, 0xcd, 0xbd, 0x4d, 0x8e
    , 0x9d, 0xed, 0xe9, 0xda, 0xd4, 0x9, 0x29, 0xcc };
private static byte[] key256 ={ 0x21, 0x23, 0x24, 0x61, 0x35, 0x34, 0x3f, 0x33,
    0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef,
    0x84, 0x63, 0x59, 0xd4, 0xcb, 0xc4, 0x97, 0xf9,
    0x96, 0xc2, 0xb3, 0x7e, 0xb0, 0xe6, 0x73, 0x52
    };
private ICryptoTransform rijndaelDecryptor, rijndaelEncryptor;
RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
rijndaelDecryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key256, iv);
rijndaelEncryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key256, iv);

public string Encrypt(string plaintext)
    {
        if (plaintext.Length < 1) return "";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext);
        byte[] newData = rijndaelEncryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(newData);
    }
```

On the c++ end, I am using CRijndael class from the code project.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1380/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Rijndael-Encryption-Decr

Here is the C++ code.

```
 CString Rijndael::DecryptAESString(const CString& strInput)
 {
CString str = _T("");
byte decipherText[128], cipherText[128];
memset(decipherText, 0, 128);
memset(cipherText, 0, 128);
if (strInput.GetLength() < 1) return _T("");
DWORD dsize = strInput.GetLength(), dsize1 = m_BlockSize;
m_Base64.Decode(strInput, &dsize, cipherText, &dsize1, 0);
DecryptBlock((char*)cipherText, (char*)decipherText);
str = decipherText;
return str;
 }
```

Plainttext is "Example". Encrypted string is ""yYRBnZb+LV8K6MQLzk3yfYqUkHlvOHh+IP8TFHIHxBI="". Decrypted text is ""ô!sc½Ñ(ŽíéÚÔ\t)Ì"".
I think my problem is related to Unicode character in C# is 2 bytes and ASII character in C++ is 1 byte. Any suggestion to fix the problem?

Comment: That encrypted sample string looks like hex, but your code uses Base64.

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext)` Don´t do this. In many cases, cutting down to pure Ascii will destroy the text. (Btw. this code will *never* use 2 byte per char. Read some things about charsets before continuing.)

Comment: Side note:  your C# encryption code is incorrect. You can use `TransformFinalBlock` only if your `bytes` size is less than Rijndael block size.
In other case you have to split `bytes` to the blocks, and apply `TransformBlock` to each except last one and `TransformFinalBlock` to the last one.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev With most encryption implementations `TransformFinalBlock` works even for longer data. In theory one could check `CanTransformMultipleBlocks`, but in practice I wouldn't bother.

Comment: The code has been tested working on C# side and C++ side for encryption and decryption. The only problem is across the two languages. I also divided the text into a block of 16 characters for encryption with padding '\0' as padding. The code also working for C# encryption and android java decryption.

Comment: Please show all code, including the part where you set encryption mode, key and IV for your C++ code.

Comment: I made a mistake for encryption mode and padding. The default mode and padding for C++ code are ECB and zeros while the C# code is CBC and PKCS7. I changed the encryption mode for C++ to CBC and the padding for C# to zeros. It works now.